# There is no implicit reference conversion from ApplicationDbContext to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

While following the [tutorial](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/dbcontext-identitydbcontext/), I am getting an error when `DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>`
which is ApplicationDbContext inherit to IdentityDbContext but when I tried to inherit DbContext it works fine.

Error Screen Shot:
[image: Error Screen Shot]

**Exception message:**

> The type 'WebExtractorPortalCore.Context.ApplicationDbContext' cannot
>   be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'DbContextOptions'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'WebExtractorPortalCore.Context.ApplicationDbContext' to
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

Comment: link to the tutorial is broken.

Comment: @SteppingRazor done i edited the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a perfect answer I need more information but form the error image you seem to be mixing ASP.Net packages and ASP.NETCore packages.

You have referenced `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` which is a .net core package but then referenced `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` which is a .net (**not** core) package.

Remove the later package and reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` instead and it should work

Comment: hi, if removed the package you mention, I would not able to use the IdentityDbContext which i needed or IdentityDbContext is not part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework package?

Comment: @klitz you are basically using the wrong version of IdentityFramework.

Comment: @klitz the core version uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;` namespace. The one in your code is from an earlier version.

Comment: @Nkosi then what is the correct package I should use?

Comment: @klitz the linked tutorial already gives the packages to be used. check it over.

Comment: @Nkosi even I added the mention package, the IdentityDbContext still referencing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and the error still produce

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the reason why I had this error was because I had two `ApplicationDbContext.cs`. One was in `Areas/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs` and another one was in `Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs` of the project file.

**Solution**

The solution is to delete one of the `Data` folders that contains the `ApplicationDbContext.cs`. For me I deleted the one in the `Areas/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs`.