# ASP.NET MVC: Error CS0311: The Type 'XYZ' can't be used as a parameter 'TContext' in generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment

I am working with .net MVC. I have ***enabled migrations*** in my project which has successfully been done. But I'm getting an error in **Migrations>Configrations.cs**. The error is following.

**CS0311: The type 'BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'**

I have enabled migration as following

```
PM>Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext
```

The code of BabyStore.DAL.ContextStore.cs is

```
    namespace BabyStore.DAL
{
    public class StoreContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And lastly The code where I'm getting error is following
**BabyStore.Migrations.Configurations.cs**

```
   namespace BabyStore.Migrations
{

using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext _context)
        {
            var categories = new List<Category>
            {
            new Category { Name = "Clothes"},
            new Category { Name = "Play and Toy" }
            };
            categories.ForEach(c => _context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, c));
            _context.SaveChanges();

            var products = new List<Product>
            {
            new Product {Name="Sleep Suit", Desccription="For Sleeping wear",Price=100,CategoryID=categories.Single(c=>c.Name=="Clouths").ID },
            new Product {Name="Vest", Desccription="For Sleeping wear",Price=200,CategoryID=categories.Single(c=>c.Name=="Clouths").ID}
             };
            products.ForEach(c => _context.Products.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, c));
            _context.SaveChange();

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error in **internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration** line

Comment: Can check this out? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980335/entity-framework-code-first-configuration-cs-seed-or-custom-initializer" or this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604618/there-is-no-implicit-reference-conversion-from-applicationdbcontext-to-microsoft". More like you are referencing to wrong ef package. In Nuget Package Manager, find "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" and install it

Comment: i suspect you are using Entity Framework 6 and running the command from Entity Framework Core

Comment: I don't have any knowledge regarding to .not Core. I'm learning .net MVC from a book (ASP.NET MVS with EntityFramwork and CSS by Lee Naylor). I'm just following the steps as mentioned in the book. But i'm stuck in the error i have mentioned above.

Comment: And Yes, the link you have shared with me, is a good resource. I have followed the instructions was given in the link and it works fortunately.
But my question is still that why it is giving an error in case if I follow every step that is given in the book?

Comment: I haven't used EF in a while but doesn't your `StoreContext` need to inherit from `DbContext`? That error message implies `TContext` is constrained to a `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about force the migration? use -force parameter

```
PM>Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext -force
```

I think there is spelling mistake. Change clouths to cloths

```
new Product {Name="Sleep Suit", Desccription="For Sleeping wear",Price=100,CategoryID=categories.Single(c=>c.Name=="Cloths").ID },
new Product {Name="Vest", Description="For Sleeping wear",Price=200,CategoryID=categories.Single(c=>c.Name=="Cloths").ID}
```

I already check the book you are refereing to which is ASP.net MVC with Entity Framework CSS and it's repo https://github.com/Apress/asp.net-mvc-w-entity-framework-css. If you check the package, it use "EntityFramework.6.1.3" which is different from .net core.

You can recreate your project in visual studio and this time round select ASP.NET Web Application(.NET Framework). The problem is due to the different entity framework package. Please refer to this [EntityFramework Core automatic migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526595/entityframework-core-automatic-migrations) for setting up automatic migration on asp.net core.

Comment: I'm afraid it is still giving an error on the same line

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BabyStore.DAL.StoreContext>

It gives error on Configuration keyword

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I got the answer above. And yes I did try what you have recommended me to do so. Both of them worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [class signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) shows that the generic argument `TContext` is constrained to type `DbContext`.

```
public class DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration where TContext : DbContext
```

Modify your `StoreContext` to inherit `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

```
public class StoreContext : DbContext
```